# A formula to group timeslots?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a column in my Google Sheet that shows timeslots for appointments in the following format:

```
07:15-07:45
09:00-09:30
12:45-13:15
16:30-17:00
```

In a new column, I would like to condense these into groups so that for instance any timeslot between 07:00-10:00 would be "Early Morning" 10:00-13:00 would be "Late Morning/Early Afternoon" etc.

How would I be able to do this with a formula?

Comment: What have you tried? stackoverflow is not a coding service.

Comment: Along with your attempt a sample of how your desired result would actually look like would be great.

Comment: what if your timeslot will be: 07:10-13:40 ?

Comment: I should have added that al timeslots are half an hour. The desired result would be a column next to it that states if the timeslot is "Early Morning" / "Late Morning/Early Afternoon" etc.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following

```
=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(IFS(
                  IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A11,"(.*)-")*1,"")<TIMEVALUE("10:00:00"),"Ear.Mor.",
                  IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A11,"(.*)-")*1,"")<TIMEVALUE("13:00:00"),"Lt.Mor.",
                  IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A11,"(.*)-")*1,"")<TIMEVALUE("16:00:00"),"Ear.Aft.",
                  IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A11,"(.*)-")*1,"")<TIMEVALUE("19:00:00"),"Lt.Aft.")))
```

OR

```
=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(IFS(
                  IFERROR(INDEX(SPLIT(A2:A11,"-"),0,1),"")<TIMEVALUE("10:00:00"),"Ear.Mor",
                  IFERROR(INDEX(SPLIT(A2:A11,"-"),0,1),"")<TIMEVALUE("13:00:00"),"Lt.Mor",
                  IFERROR(INDEX(SPLIT(A2:A11,"-"),0,1),"")<TIMEVALUE("16:00:00"),"Ear.Aft",
                  IFERROR(INDEX(SPLIT(A2:A11,"-"),0,1),"")<TIMEVALUE("19:00:00"),"Lt.Aft")))
```

[image]

*(You can adjust ranges to your needs)*

Functions used:

- [`ArrayFormula`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)
- [`IFERROR`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304)
- [`IFS`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7014145)
- [`INDEX`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242)
- [`TIMEVALUE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3267350)
- [`REGEXEXTRACT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244)
- [`SPLIT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that to separate beginning time of appointment and end of it to different columns. Then you can write a formula using `if` statement like this: `IF(AND(D2 > TIME(7,0,0), F2 < TIME(10,0,0)),"Early Morning"," another if statement ")` Assume that D2 is beginning of appointment and F2 is the end. I might have made a mistake but overall idea is like that. Please refer to those links for more information about if statements and timeslots:

https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-if-function

https://www.excelhow.net/how-to-compare-time-difference-with-certain-time-in-excel.html